# Azure DevOps ionic Error building android

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, azure-devops, ionic3, cordova-plugins

While running Azure DevOps tasks for cordova to build android getting following error, but the same code build fine in local machine!

```
  [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
  cordova platform add android@8.0.0 --verbose exited with exit code 1.
```

Even including --verbose doesnt give any more insights into whats went wrong! Any clues on resolving this?

Log :

`2020-06-10T12:07:08.9595670Z Updating icons at platforms/android/app/src/main/res
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9595970Z Updating splash screens at platforms/android/app/src/main/res
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9596290Z This app does not have additional resource files defined
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9596560Z Prepared android project successfully
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9597390Z Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-add-swift-support for hook "after_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-add-swift-support/add-swift-support.js
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9597890Z Resolving module name for glob => glob
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9598130Z Saving android@8.0.0 into platforms.json
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9598640Z --save flag or autosave detected
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9598910Z Saving android@~8.0.0 into config.xml file ...
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9599200Z adding android to cordova.platforms array in package.json
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9599480Z No scripts found for hook "after_platform_add".
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9599780Z [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9600000Z

2020-06-10T12:07:08.9600570Z         cordova platform add android@8.0.0 --verbose exited with exit code 1.
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9600850Z

2020-06-10T12:07:08.9601610Z         Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9602390Z 2020-06-10T12:07:08.134Z ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9603200Z 2020-06-10T12:07:08.134Z ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 functions
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9603970Z 2020-06-10T12:07:08.162Z ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1)
2020-06-10T12:07:08.9604510Z [0m]`

Comment: Are you certain that the Android environment is install on the ADO machine?

Comment: yes i have verified it and have command to update sdkmanager as-well, which succeeds with no error, but am not getting 'What went wrong' details though.

Comment: Can you share ionic info output ?

Comment: Ionic:
   Ionic CLI          : 6.10.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
Cordova:
   Cordova CLI       : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, browser 5.0.3
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.5.3, (and 21 other plugins)
Utility:
   cordova-res (update available: 0.14.0) : 0.10.0
   native-run (update available: 1.0.0)   : 0.2.9
   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v12.18.0
   npm        : 6.14.4
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.5